# $elemMatch equivalent in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I need to know the equivalent code in spring data mongo db to the code below:-

```
db.inventory.find( {
                     qty: { $all: [
                                    { "$elemMatch" : { size: "M", num: { $gt: 50} } },
                                    { "$elemMatch" : { num : 100, color: "green" } }
                                  ] }
                   } )
```

Comment: I'm not even sure at a glance if that query is even valid. But really, tools like "sping data mongo" only really provide "helper methods". You don't "have to" use them. Just use the native mongo methods instead along with the structures they expect.

Comment: this is a valid query. Please check here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Answer (score 33):

I am able to get the answer. This can be done in Spring data mongodb using following code

```
Query query = new Query();      
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("qty").elemMatch(Criteria.where("size").is("M").and("num").gt(50).elemMatch(Criteria.where("num").is(100).and("color").is("green"))));
```

Comment: Then how do you execute query?

Comment: copy-paste driver development!

Comment: @Anna Ideally it'll be `mongoTemplate.find(<query>, <Classname>.class);`

Answer (score 4):

I think query in your answer generated below query

```
{ "qty" : { "$elemMatch" : { "num" : 100 , "color" : "green"}}}
```

I think thats not you need.

Its only check last elemMatch expression not all.

Try with this.

```
query = new Query();
Criteria first = Criteria.where("qty").elemMatch(Criteria.where("size").is("M").and("num").gt(50));
Criteria two = Criteria.where("qty").elemMatch(Criteria.where("num").is(100).and("color").is("green"));
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(first, two));
```

Comment: Thanks you saved my day.

Comment: @Chamly how to write `first` and `two` criteria in 1 single line?

Comment: @mi_mo try this. query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("qty").elemMatch(Criteria.where("size").is("M").and("num").gt(50).elemMatch(Criteria.where("num").is(100).and("color").is("green"))));

Answer (score 1):

Just implemented `$all` with `$elemMatch` with spring data Criteria API:

```
var elemMatch1 = new Criteria()
.elemMatch(Criteria.where("size").is("M").and("num").gt(50));
var elemMatch2 = new Criteria()
.elemMatch(Criteria.where("num").is(100).and("color").is("green"));

var criteria = Criteria.where("qty")
.all(elemMatch1.getCriteriaObject(), elemMatch2.getCriteriaObject());

mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(criteria), Inventory.class);
```

**Note:** important part is calling `getCriteriaObject` method inside `Criteria.all(...)` for each `Criteria.elemMatch(...)` element.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make @Vaibhav answer a bit more clearer.

given Document in DB

```
{
   "modified": true,
   "items": [
     {
      "modified": true,
      "created": false
     },
     {
      "modified": false,
      "created": false
     },
     {
      "modified": true,
      "created": true
     }
   ]
}
```

You could do following Query if you need items where both attribute of an item are true.

```
 Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("modified").is(true));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("items")
            .elemMatch(Criteria.where("modified").is(true)
                    .and("created").is(true)));
```

here an example how to query with OR in elemMatch

```
 Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("modified").is(true));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("items")
                .elemMatch(new Criteria().orOperator(
                        Criteria.where("modified").is(true), 
                        Criteria.where("created").is(true))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i implemented too in Kotlin, its is extended about if statements to create dynamic query :)

```
val map = segmentFilter.segmentValueMap.map {
            val segmentCriteria = where("segment").isEqualTo(it.key)
            if (it.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                segmentCriteria.and("segmentValue").`in`(it.value)
            }
            if (sovOverviewInDateRange != null) {
                segmentCriteria.and("date").lte(sovOverviewInDateRange.recent).gte(sovOverviewInDateRange.older)
            }
            Criteria().elemMatch(segmentCriteria)
        }
        criteriaQuery.and("sovOverview").all(map.map { it.criteriaObject })
```

```
  sovOverviews: {
      $all: [
        {
         $elemMatch: {
        segment: "Velikost",
        segmentValue: "S"
         }
      },
      {
         $elemMatch: {
        segment: "Kategorie"
         }
      }
        ]
      }
```