# Querying by inner object field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I have a rather trivial problem but I constantly get an error.

So I have a `Request` class which contains a list field `calls`. And I would like using Mongo to query requests by the `to`-field of `Call`-object (for example, to find all the requests that contain at least one call to a person `Alice`).

```
@Document
public class Request {
   @Id 
   String id;
   String content;
   List<Call> calls;

   //getters setters etc.
}

public class Call {
    String from;
    String to;
    DateTime timestamp;

    //getters setters etc.
}
```

In my repository I tried to execute different kinds of queries. But they all return an error.

```
interface RequestRepo extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Request, String> {

    @Query("select r from Request r where r.calls.to = :userId") 
    // I also tried "@Query({ 'calls.to' : ?0 }")
    Flux<Request> findAllByCallTo(@Param("userId") String userId);
}
```

But unfortunately I always get an error:

`readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.`

What could be the problem and what is the correct way to write the query?

Comment: might not be using the same things you are using but, normally we use the element match for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/28875649/1692147